# Походження слова "вінтаж"

Tags: етимологія

Визначення з СУМ-20

> ***[ВІНТАЖ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=190133&page=474)***
>
> 1. Речі минулих років, зібрані в колекції (одяг, взуття, вино і т. ін.). *Вінтаж тим і цінний, що ексклюзивну дизайнерську, неймовірно
>    дорогу річ із колекцій минулих років можна купити досить дешево* (із
>    журн.).
> 2. Напрям у дизайнерському, мистецькому та ін. стилі, якому притаманне використання тенденцій минулих часів. *Актуальний сьогодні стиль
>    вінтаж диктує свої правила: нові аромати – це вчасно згадані старі*
>    (із журн.).

Яке походження має слово "вінтаж"?

Comment: Запозичене vintage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово "вінтаж" походить від французького "Vintage", що означає "витримка вина" (саме так, це слово має зв'язок із виноробством і також є аналогом до слова "[мілезим](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC)" в англомовних країнах). На [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)) дається інформація: "Термін "vintage" належав до лексикону виноробів і позначав високоякісне вино, що витримувалось в ідеальних умовах не один десяток років. Під цим словом розумілись неймовірний смак, ексклюзивність, і, головне, неможливість виробництва аналогів. Також під вінтажем розуміють раритети у світі моди і стилю."

Крім того саме слово "[Vintage](http://dictionary-economics.ru/word/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6)" походить від латинського vindemia ("vinum" - "вино" та "demere" - "відбирати"). Тому навіть на тій же Вікіпедії зустрічаємо термін "вінтажне вино".